# Android Navigation goes back to title screen

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

My app right now has three screens: Home, Rockets and Company. When I open the app, it's on Home screen and there's a hamburger icon that opens the Navigation drawer. The problem is that when I select Rockets or Company from the drawer, the hamburger icon is replaced with a back arrow. Clicking on the arrow will navigate back to the Home screen. The hamburger icon reappears when I'm on Home screen.

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/midnight_blue" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_host"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`nav_menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_home"
        />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_data"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/rocketsDataFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_rocket"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_rockets_data"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/companyDataFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_company"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_company_data"
            />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_launches"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/past_launches"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_prev"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_launches_past"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/upcoming_launches"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_launches_upcoming"
            />
    </group>

</menu>
```

`nav_graph.xml`

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rocketman.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rocketsDataFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rocketman.rocket.RocketsDataFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_menu_rockets_data"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_rockets_data"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/companyDataFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rocketman.company.CompanyDataFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_menu_company_data"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_company_data"
        />

</navigation>
```

And finally, `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_nav_host) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarMain)
        setupNavigationDrawer()
    }

    private fun setupNavigationDrawer() {
        navController.let { navController ->
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
                this,
                navController,
                binding.drawerLayout
            )
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, binding.drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I make my screens have access to the Navigation Drawer instead of being navigation paths of Home screen?

In other words, I want my screen to all be able to go to another screen through Navigation drawer instead of going from that screen to Home screen and then go to another screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't use `AppBarConfiguration` in your code which will resolve your problem.

**AppBarConfiguration**:
NavigationUI uses an AppBarConfiguration object to manage the behavior of the Navigation button in the upper-left corner of your app's display area. The Navigation button’s behavior changes depending on whether the user is at a top-level destination.

See the doc's for more understanding [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

I have updated the code of your Activity below. If Navigation Extensions Functions show's error makes sure to have these dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.

**Dependencies**:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
```

**Updated Activity Code**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_nav_host) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarMain)
        setupNavigationDrawer()
    }

    private fun setupNavigationDrawer() {
        navController.let { navController ->
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                    R.id.homeFragment, R.id.rocketsDataFragment, R.id.companyDataFragment), binding.drawerLayout)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
      
        }     
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If you're using Android Studio **version 4.1.2** by creating a new project (Navigation Drawer Activity Template) it will setup the project with AppBarConfiguration with all needed dependencies. So you can also try that.

Comment: Excellent, it works now. Only one small thing left - the burger icon becomes an arrow after clicking on either `Company` or `Rocket` despite it behaving correctly (opening the drawer).

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh did you make a new project using Navigation Drawer Activity Template?